# Unit test result does not show on SonarQube Dashboard for nodejs

Tags: node.js, sonarqube, sonar-runner, sonarjs

**SonarQube Version** : 6.0.0
**SonarJS** : 2.17.0.3154

**Issue**

The main aim is to display coverage report and the unit test result in SonarQube dashboard. Though I am able to get the coverage report but not able to get the unit test result in SonarQube dashboard .
I have been using the mocha for unit testing and istanbul nyc for code coverage. The report generated by mocha is in xml format using the package mocha-sonar-reporter and the coverage report is in lcov format .

[sonarqube dashboard](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tpnTq.png)

**Sonar.Property File**

```
sonar.projectKey=unittest
sonar.projectName=unittest 
sonar.projectVersion=1.0.0
sonar.sources=src/
sonar.tests=test/
sonar.language=js
sonar.sourceEncoding=UTF-8
sonar.javascript.jstestdriver.reportsPath=/home/jenkinsbot/workspace/devops_stuffs/reports
sonar.javascript.lcov.reportPath=/home/jenkinsbot/workspace/devops_stuffs/reports/lcov.info
```

**SonarQube log** :

```
_[Pipeline] wrap
Injecting SonarQube environment variables using the configuration: Sonar(dk.147)
[Pipeline] {
[Pipeline] sh
[e_feature_COS-239-unit-test-P23YKERWYLNSD6K3ISKUHA5NSJTRN6K7DRJGKI5QLG6LTD3HHOPA] Running shell script

/home/jenkinsbot/sonar-scanner-2.9.0.670/bin/sonar-scanner
INFO: Scanner configuration file: /home/jenkinsbot/sonar-scanner-2.9.0.670/conf/sonar-scanner.properties
INFO: Project root configuration file: /home/jenkinsbot/workspace//sonar-project.properties
INFO: SonarQube Scanner 2.9.0.670
INFO: Java 1.8.0_131 Oracle Corporation (64-bit)
INFO: Linux 4.4.0-92-generic amd64
INFO: User cache: /home/jenkinsbot/.sonar/cache
INFO: Load global repositories
INFO: Load global repositories (done) | time=94ms
INFO: User cache: /home/jenkinsbot/.sonar/cache
INFO: Load plugins index
INFO: Load plugins index (done) | time=4ms
INFO: SonarQube server 6.0
INFO: Default locale: "en_US", source code encoding: "UTF-8"
INFO: Process project properties
INFO: Load project repositories
INFO: Load project repositories (done) | time=100ms
INFO: Load quality profiles
INFO: Load quality profiles (done) | time=17ms
INFO: Load active rules
INFO: Load active rules (done) | time=231ms
INFO: Publish mode
INFO: ------------- Scan cosmicunittest
INFO: Language is forced to js
INFO: Load server rules
INFO: Load server rules (done) | time=71ms
INFO: Base dir: /home/jenkinsbot/workspace/
INFO: Working dir: /home/jenkinsbot/workspace/eP23YKERWYLNSD6K3ISKUHA5NSJTRN6K7DRJGKI5QLG6LTD3HHOPA/.scannerwork
INFO: Source paths: src
INFO: Test paths: test
INFO: Source encoding: UTF-8, default locale: en_US
INFO: Index files
INFO: 152 files indexed
INFO: Quality profile for js: LogPoint Way
INFO: Sensor Lines Sensor
INFO: Sensor Lines Sensor (done) | time=33ms
INFO: Sensor SCM Sensor
INFO: Sensor SCM Sensor (done) | time=20ms
INFO: Sensor JavaScript Squid Sensor
INFO: 138 source files to be analyzed
INFO: Unit Test Coverage Sensor is started
INFO: 138/138 source files have been analyzed
INFO: Analysing [/home/jenkinsbot/workspace/reports/lcov.info]
INFO: Integration Test Coverage Sensor is started
INFO: Overall Coverage Sensor is started
INFO: Analysing [/home/jenkinsbot/workspace/reports/lcov.info]
INFO: Sensor JavaScript Squid Sensor (done) | time=4852ms
INFO: Sensor XmlFileSensor
INFO: Sensor XmlFileSensor (done) | time=1ms
INFO: Sensor Zero Coverage Sensor
INFO: Sensor Zero Coverage Sensor (done) | time=76ms
INFO: Sensor Code Colorizer Sensor
INFO: Sensor Code Colorizer Sensor (done) | time=3ms
INFO: Sensor CPD Block Indexer
INFO: DefaultCpdBlockIndexer is used for js
INFO: Sensor CPD Block Indexer (done) | time=1ms
INFO: Calculating CPD for 129 files
INFO: CPD calculation finished
INFO: Analysis report generated in 222ms, dir size=903 KB
INFO: Analysis reports compressed in 300ms, zip size=512 KB
INFO: Analysis report uploaded in 24ms
INFO: ANALYSIS SUCCESSFUL, you can browse http://test/dashboard/index/unittest
INFO: Note that you will be able to access the updated dashboard once the server has processed the submitted analysis report
INFO: More about the report processing at test
INFO: Task total time: 7.649 s
INFO: ------------------------------------------------------------------------
INFO: EXECUTION SUCCESS
INFO: ------------------------------------------------------------------------
INFO: Total time: 8.784s
INFO: Final Memory: 61M/551M
INFO: ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // wrap
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // script
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // node
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // stage
[Pipeline] End of Pipeline
Finished: SUCCESS_
```

Answer (score 1):

Answered here https://github.com/SonarSource/sonar-javascript/issues/751

Unit test results import is not provided anymore by SonarJS. For that you should use SQ's native feature [Generic Test Data](https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/Generic+Test+Data) (since SQ 6.2). If you use SQ < 6.2 use this plugin https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/PLUG/Generic+Test+Coverage.

Comment: I tried with Generic Test Coverage plugin but the XML generated by mocha tool with mocha-sonar-reporter plugin is not parsed by this plugin . I have added the sonar.property as sonar.genericcoverage.unitTestReportPaths= testpath. I checked the official documentation for Generic Test Coverage where the sample XML shown is in different format as mine generated by mocha .

Comment: @sudeepparajuli Even i tried generating Generic Test Coverage with sonar.property as sonar.genericcoverage.unitTestReportPaths= testpath added in sonar.property. The xml generated has testsuite as root node where as per  official documentation it should have testExecutions as root node. Getting parsing error as Unknown XML node, expected "testExecutions" but got "testsuite". I am still looking for a solution, did you get it worked for you and how , please help.